# Trouble redirecting sub.example.com to sub.example.com/directory/

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a website set up at example.com/directory/ currently. /directory/ is set up to display different contents depending on the subdomain, that part is working fine. I'm having trouble editing my httpd.conf file to work correctly though.

Obviously I can only set up my A records for sub.example.com to point to example.com and not example.com/directory/ so I've set up some rules in my httpd to get around this, but they don't seem to be working. This is what I've got so far:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^sub1\.example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^((?!directory).*)$ /directory/$1 [NC,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^sub2\.example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^((?!directory).*)$ /directory/$1 [NC,L]
```

What seems to be happening though is those rules just direct each subdomain to example.com/directory and drop the subdomain completely. I'm a little lost as to what I need to change here, I'm not very well versed in Apache.

I know this should be simple, but I can't seem to find any documentation that is straightforward enough for me to understand, does anybody have any pointers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be using separate sub-directories for each subdomain like this:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^sub1\.example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^((?!folder1/).*)$ folder1/$1 [NC,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^sub2\.example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^((?!folder2/).*)$ folder2/$1 [NC,L]
```

Where `folder1` is sub-directory for `sub1` domain and `folder2` is sub-directory for `sub2` domain.

Comment: I can't use separate subdirectories as I have a Magento install in /folder/ and Magento uses the domain that accesses it to decide what content to display. The code in your example gives me a 400 Bad Request error. If I add a slash like `RewriteRule ^((?!folder/).*)$ /folder/$1 [NC,L]` then I get sent to example.com/folder.

Comment: For anyone reading, this was correct, but I didn't realize I had a lot of other mod_rewrite rules in .htaccess files. I went ahead and put these rules in the base directory .htaccess file instead of in httpd.conf and everything worked fine.